# Typo3-Fluid doesnt render my Content Elements | Error : "Content Element with uid "189" and type "text" has no rendering definition!"

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

i am trying to setup a Typo3 (v.8.7.27) Homepage using Fluid and Backendlayouts.
First i created a Backendlayout (uid = 4) and also a new Template-Html (...\Resources\Private\Templates\Page\Test1). I edited my setup.typoscript for the extension and added the following Code (actuelly just the part with the 4 / 4.)

```
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      templateName = TEXT
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
         key.data = pagelayout

         pagets__site_theme_default = TEXT
         pagets__site_theme_default.value = Default

         4 = TEXT
         4.value = Test1

         default = TEXT
         default.value = Default
      }
```

My Test1.html looked like this:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">
   <main role="main">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '11', wrap: '<div class=\"hero\">|</div>'}" />
   </main>
</f:section>
```

Here is the Problem: Everything worked but it didnt render the Content - instead it "wrapped" the Error Msg: " Content Element with uid "189" and type "text" has no rendering definition!"

```
<div class="hero">
   <p style="background-color: yellow; padding: 0.5em 1em;">
      <strong>ERROR:</strong> Content Element with uid "189" and type "text" has no rendering definition!
   </p>
</div>
```

In the Backend i added this Backendlayout to the Rootpage and created the Content Element for colPos 11 - its just a simple Text. I have problems understand what could be wrong as it correctly shows the uid of the Contentelement in the Error msg... Any idears?

Thank you for your help! And please write if you need more information
Daniel

Comment: Did you include "Fluid Styled Content" in your TypoScript template? (template module >click on the page with you TS template > click "edit the whole template record" > Tab "Includes" > Include static (from extensions)

Comment: I included it in my custom theme extension. I guess if fluid wouldnt be included the viewhelper should not work at all, right? I included my custom extension which then included FSC in its typoscript.

Comment: Can you check the typoScript settings you made in - click in backend: Template on the left side, your rootpage, selcect "TypoScript Object Browser", select "Setup", open [tt_content] and search [text] = < Is there a "lib.contentElement" or a "lib.fluidContent". Search for that when you scroll down and open [lib], open contentElement or fluidContent und check your template/partial/layout pathes.

Comment: Thank you @bandanh i didnt knew this part of the template-backend-area. I found my mistake and replaced a @ include ... with <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: ...> in a typoscript file in my extension.  Thank you very much! Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: Write the answer you found by yourself and accept it, I guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import of Fluid had a syntax mistake. The Problem is fixed - thanks to @bandanh. If you have a problem like this check your TypoScript Objekt Browser and look for unexpected stuff / missing Objects.

Thank you,
Daniel